# What does ::cetp::PAL mean?

Tags: tcl

I have a question about CETP(Common Expect Test Platform), it is a TCL testing platform.

I saw the following code

```
::cetp::PAL
```

what does this mean?

Comment: There's a good write-up about Tcl namespaces at http://www.beedub.com/book/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a command/procedure in the ::cetp [Namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm) which is named PAL and calls it with no arguments. I don't know what the PAL command does, but the CETP documentation should show you.

The few links i could find that showed ::cept::PAL commands suggest that it is some kind of logging command that outputs its argument to some log file.

Comment: It could also be a variable name that isn't dereferenced (talking about the `PAL` variable in the `cetp` namespace that is a child of the global namespace). Impossible to tell from such a short fragment.

Comment: True, but i found some code fragments that use ::cept::PAL like one would typically use puts with just one arg. So its likely that it is a command/proc.

Comment: someone tell me the cetp::PAL is used to write information into log.but where I can get cetp documentation? I feel like it is unreachable.